# How to get the WiFi noise level in Android?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wireless

I want to implement an app which measures the quality of the WiFi signal from an indoor environment. From my research I found that the best way to get an accurate measurement is not to get only the RSSI but instead to use the SNR (Signal to Noise Ratio).

How can I obtain the noise level from the Android SDK? As I heard, there is no API available for this. However, I've found a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getEvdoSnr()) which provides the SNR ([getEvdoSnr()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getEvdoSnr())). Unfortunately, this one works only for a GSM/CDMA signal and not for a WiFi connection.

Is anything possible to calculate the SNR in Android? I believe that's doable because I've found an app on Play store (called WiFi SNR) which successfully measures this ratio.

---

**NOTE**: The Android ScanResult doesn't provide the noise level, even if it's specified in the official documentation:

> Describes information about a detected access point. In addition to the attributes described here, the supplicant keeps track of quality, **noise**, and maxbitrate attributes, but does not currently report them to external clients.

Comment: no progress on the subject? Did you find a way to get the noise level?

Comment: @narb Still not found a solution for this, unfortunately. I've let only the RSSI in the App as a measurement, but still not a precise way to measure a signal.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html.

> Describes information about a detected access point. In addition to the attributes described here, **the supplicant keeps track of quality, noise, and maxbitrate attributes**, but does not currently report them to external clients.

I bet something like this will give to you desired information:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
for (ScanResult result : wifiManager.getScanResults()) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this before and there wasn't any relevant data which describe the noise level. However, I've integrated again this snippet and all I receive is this: 

`scanResult= SSID: HI-LINK_006B, BSSID: 3c:33:00:a2:00:6a, HESSID: <none>, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -85, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 101848429875, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm)`

Comment: either, as described in API: **`Use calculateSignalLevel(int, int)` to convert this number into an absolute signal level which can be displayed to a user.**??

Comment: Okay, this method is indeed used to classify the power strength (by levels), but still for RSSI signal. What I receive from ScanResults doesn't contain the noise signal (which is represented in dBm as RSSI). The noise should be a separated measurement.